# Why can I not replace old value with new value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a very simple in-browser game that has a man and a coin and the objective of the game is to simply use the arrow keys on the keyboard to get the randomly placed coins as many times as you want. At the top I have a score counter and instead of replacing the new score with the old score, the new score just gets added on to the old one (ex: 1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345 when really the score should just be 5).

Here's my function:

```
const score = document.querySelector("#score");

let total = 0;

const moveCoin = () => {
  const width = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);
  const height = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight);
  coin.style.top = `${height}px`;
  coin.style.left = `${width}px`;
  total += 1;
  console.log(total);
  score.append(total);
};

moveCoin();
```

and a picture of what I'm seeing:

[image]

Comment: what is `score.append(total)`? please post it's code

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: The append is the problem. Please post a complete example

Comment: try: `score.innerText=total`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
score.innerText = total;
```

Because `append` function is appends to the end of the score.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `append`, use the `innerText` or `innerHTML` properties. You can see more detailed examples in [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp) and [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText). Hope this helps.